# Add item to array in VBScript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

How do you add an item to an existing array in VBScript?

Is there a VBScript equivalent to the push function in Javascript?

i.e.

myArray has three items, "Apples", "Oranges", and "Bananas" and I want to add "Watermelons" to the end of the array.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Arrays are not very dynamic in VBScript. You'll have to use the [ReDim Preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) statement to grow the existing array so it can accommodate an extra item:

```
ReDim Preserve yourArray(UBound(yourArray) + 1)
yourArray(UBound(yourArray)) = "Watermelons"
```

Comment: Be aware that `Redim Preserve` copies the whole array every time you use it. In other words it has n**2 complexity in the big-O notation.

Comment: @user, copying the whole array has linear complexity (`O(n)`), not quadratic (`O(n²)`).

Comment: Of course making one copy is linear. What I meant here was building up the array in this manner. Populating a 100k array versus a 200k array using Redim Preserve will definitely take 4x as long, not 2x). This is not just theory, you can try it for yourself and you'll see. What I normally do (and is simple to implement but means a huge performance boost) is to increase the upper bound by a factor 1.1 every time the index is about to become higher than the upper bound.

Comment: I guess you still initialize the this "dynamic" array with Dim yourArray?

Comment: @Pixie, you can indeed use `Dim`, but then you have to specify empty subscripts to make the array "dynamic": `Dim yourArray()`

Comment: I have a type mismatch: ´UBound´ when giving the ReDim Preserve statement (after initializing with Dim)...

Comment: @Pixie, right, looks like `Dim` creates a array without size, not an actual dynamic array (the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zexdsyc0.aspx) is unclear about this and says *dynamic* all over the place). `UBound()` cannot be applied to such arrays. Conclusion: use `ReDim` everywhere and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 15):

For your copy and paste ease

```
' add item to array
Function AddItem(arr, val)
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr)) = val
    AddItem = arr
End Function
```

Used like so

```
a = Array()
a = AddItem(a, 5)
a = AddItem(a, "foo")
```

Answer (score 12):

There are a few ways, not including a custom COM or ActiveX object

1. ReDim Preserve
2. Dictionary object, which can have string keys and search for them
3. ArrayList .Net Framework Class, which has many methods including:
   sort (forward, reverse, custom), insert, remove,
   binarysearch, equals, toArray, and toString

<del>With the code below, I found Redim Preserve is fastest below 54000, Dictionary is fastest from 54000 to 690000, and Array List is fastest above 690000. I tend to use ArrayList for pushing because of the sorting and array conversion.</del>

user326639 provided FastArray, which is pretty much the fastest.

Dictionaries are useful for searching for the value and returning the index (i.e. field names), or for grouping and aggregation (histograms, group and add, group and concatenate strings, group and push sub-arrays).  When grouping on keys, set CompareMode for case in/sensitivity, and check the "exists" property before "add"-ing.

Redim wouldn't save much time for one array, but it's useful for a dictionary of arrays.

```
'pushtest.vbs
imax = 10000
value = "Testvalue"
s = imax & " of """ & value & """" 

t0 = timer 'ArrayList Method
Set o = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For i = 0 To imax
  o.Add value
Next
s = s & "[AList " & FormatNumber(timer - t0, 3, -1) & "]"
Set o = Nothing

t0 = timer 'ReDim Preserve Method
a = array()
For i = 0 To imax
  ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
  a(UBound(a)) = value
Next
s = s & "[ReDim " & FormatNumber(timer - t0, 3, -1) & "]"
Set a = Nothing

t0 = timer 'Dictionary Method
Set o = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 0 To imax
  o.Add i, value
Next
s = s & "[Dictionary " & FormatNumber(timer - t0, 3, -1) & "]"
Set o = Nothing

t0 = timer 'Standard array
Redim a(imax)
For i = 0 To imax
  a(i) = value
Next
s = s & "[Array " & FormatNumber(timer - t0, 3, -1) & "]" & vbCRLF
Set a = Nothing

t0 = timer 'Fast array
a = array()
For i = 0 To imax
 ub = UBound(a)
 If i>ub Then ReDim Preserve a(Int((ub+10)*1.1))
 a(i) = value
Next
ReDim Preserve a(i-1)
s = s & "[FastArr " & FormatNumber(timer - t0, 3, -1) & "]"
Set a = Nothing

MsgBox s

'  10000 of "Testvalue" [ArrayList 0.156][Redim 0.016][Dictionary 0.031][Array 0.016][FastArr 0.016]
'  54000 of "Testvalue" [ArrayList 0.734][Redim 0.672][Dictionary 0.203][Array 0.063][FastArr 0.109]
' 240000 of "Testvalue" [ArrayList 3.172][Redim 5.891][Dictionary 1.453][Array 0.203][FastArr 0.484]
' 690000 of "Testvalue" [ArrayList 9.078][Redim 44.785][Dictionary 8.750][Array 0.609][FastArr 1.406]
'1000000 of "Testvalue" [ArrayList 13.191][Redim 92.863][Dictionary 18.047][Array 0.859][FastArr 2.031]
```

Comment: May i suggest you add this piece of code:      t0 = timer 'Fast array
    a = array()
    For i = 0 To imax
      ub = UBound(a)
      If i>ub Then ReDim Preserve a(Int ((ub+10)*1.1))
      a(i) = value
    Next
    ReDim Preserve a(i-1)
    s = s & "[FastArr " & FormatNumber(timer - t0, 3, -1) & "]"
    Set a = Nothing

Comment: Thanks! I never would have been able to think up that one

Comment: @mgr326639 What is up with the final `ReDim Preserve a(i-1)`?

Comment: @sirdank The final `Redim Preserve` serves to set the upper bound of the array to the correct value. In other words, to get rid of unused reserved space. Now you can use `For each itm in arr` and the itteration will stop where it should; at the item that was meant to be the last item in your array.

Answer (score 4):

Slight change to the FastArray from above:

```
'pushtest.vbs
imax = 10000000
value = "Testvalue"
s = imax & " of """ & value & """" 

t0 = timer 'Fast array
a = array()
ub = UBound(a)
For i = 0 To imax
 If i>ub Then 
    ReDim Preserve a(Int((ub+10)*1.1))
    ub = UBound(a)
 End If
 a(i) = value
Next
ReDim Preserve a(i-1)
s = s & "[FastArr " & FormatNumber(timer - t0, 3, -1) & "]"

MsgBox s
```

There is no point in checking `UBound(a)` in every cycle of the for if we know exactly when it changes.

I've changed it so that it checks does `UBound(a)` just before the for starts and then only every time the `ReDim` is called

On my computer the old method took 7.52 seconds for an imax of 10 millions.

The new method took 5.29 seconds for an imax of also 10 millions, which signifies a performance increase of over 20% (for 10 millions tries, obviously this percentage has a direct relationship to the number of tries)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Charles Clayton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538388/6560697), but slightly simplified...

```
' add item to array
Sub AddArrayElement(arr, val)
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr)) = val
End Sub
```

Used like so

```
a = Array()
AddArrayElement(a, 5)
AddArrayElement(a, "foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

this some kind of late but anyway and it is also somewhat tricky

```
 dim arrr 
  arr= array ("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas")
 dim temp_var 
 temp_var = join (arr , "||") ' some character which will not occur is regular strings 
 if len(temp_var) > 0 then 
  temp_var = temp_var&"||Watermelons" 
end if 
arr  = split(temp_var , "||") ' here you got new elemet in array ' 
for each x in arr
response.write(x & "<br />")
next'
```

review and tell me if this can work 
or initially  you save all data in string and later split for array

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer** Or **Why '[tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23517353/603855)' is bad**:

```
>> a = Array(1)
>> a = Split(Join(a, "||") & "||2", "||")
>> WScript.Echo a(0) + a(1)
>>
12
```